# Fundamental theorem of calculus for step functions

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

Why in the proof they say it's equal to const+ $ \phi t$ (first line, next page) - where does the $p_{j-1}$ vanish? Also if $t=p_j$ then how does $p_j - p_{j-1}$ equal to 0? (since they imply it vanishes?) Also isn't the derivative supposed to be equal to 0, like step functions are piece wise constant, hence at some specific point the change in y would be $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-\varphi_j p_{j-1}$ is a constant, and so it is absorbed into the 'Const' term of 
Const $+$ $\varphi_j t$.

$t\ne p_j$ in general.

You are confusing the step function and its *integral* $I(t)$. Indeed, the derivative of the step function is zero (except at the points of discontinuity). But, the integral is $I(t) = \varphi_j t + C$ for a constant $C$. This varies linearly with $t$, and so its derivative is $\varphi_j$.

Addendum:

Consider a plot of $\varphi(t)$ vs $t$.

If $t$ changes by $\Delta t$, then the area (and hence $I(t)$) changes by $\varphi_j \Delta t$.

So, its *rate of change of area* (i.e. derivative of $I(t)$) is $\varphi_j$.

Comment: I'm confused. Is 'const' = constant(some a in R)?. So then Constant+phi.t is informally saying ''A constant plus phi.t? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: But then if the integral I(t) is a sum of constants, then how is the derivative of it is not equal to 0? What am I missing? I'm struggling to visualise this in my head..

Comment: $t$ is not a constant. It is changing, and its change causes $I(t)$ to change. I've added how to visualize this in the answer.